# How to update an array in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this array with an object inside and would like to update `said` so that there is some text inside.

[image]

code:

```
ratePost (postId, postLikes) {
  let docId = `${this.currentUser.uid}`

  fb.usersCollection.doc(docId).update({
    gotRates: [
      { said: postLikes }
    ]
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('work')
  })
}
```

But this will only overwrite the whole array.

Comment: Doug Stevenson I already did this but it does not helped me

Answer (score 2):

You need to use set and not update, with merge as true, to make sure you don't overwrite the whole array, check the set documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

```
ratePost (postId, postLikes) {
  let docId = `${this.currentUser.uid}/gotRates/0`

  fb.usersCollection.doc(docId).update({
    said: postLikes
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('work')
  })
}
```

Comment: it does not work

Comment: overwrite again

Comment: check after edit? problem is it does erase the whole array while you should be specifying the index for which you're rewriting the property

Comment: this with gotRates[0] does not work

Comment: try the one I just edited ?

Comment: `yes but does not work